# Setting an array element with a sequence (MFCC+fastDTW, Python)

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi2, voice-recognition, mfcc

I want to build Voice command project by using RPi and python. I use MFCC and fastDTW to match that voice but I got this error and I have no idea how to fix it. Here the code...

```
def fastdtw(x, y, radius=1, dist=lambda a, b: abs(a - b)):
    min_time_size = radius + 2

    if len(x) < min_time_size or len(y) < min_time_size:
        return dtw(x, y, window = None, dist=dist)

    x_shrinked = __reduce_by_half(x)
    y_shrinked = __reduce_by_half(y)
    distance, path = fastdtw(x_shrinked, y_shrinked, radius=radius, dist=dist)
    window = __expand_window(path, len(x), len(y), radius)
    return dtw(x, y, window, dist=dist)


def dtw(x, y, window=None, dist=lambda a, b: abs(a - b)):
    len_x, len_y = len(x), len(y)
    if window is None:
        window = [(i, j) for i in xrange(len_x) for j in xrange(len_y)]
    window = [(i + 1, j + 1) for i, j in window]
    D = np.full((len_x+1, len_y+1), np.inf, dtype=('f4, i4, i4'))
    D[0, 0] = (0, 0, 0)
    for i, j in window:
        D[i, j] = min((D[i-1, j][0], i-1, j), (D[i, j-1][0], i, j-1), (D[i-1, j-1][0], i-1, j-1), key=lambda a: a[0])
        D[i, j][0] += dist(x[i-1], y[j-1])
    path = []
    i, j = len_x, len_y
    while not (i == j == 0):
        path.append((i-1, j-1))
        i, j = D[i, j][1], D[i, j][2]
    path.reverse()
    return (D[len_x, len_y][0], path)
```

Run file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
from features import mfcc
from features import logfbank
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import time
from numpy.linalg import norm
import unittest
import numpy as np
from fastdtw import fastdtw, dtw
import bisect
from six.moves import xrange
from collections import defaultdict

start = time.time()
(rate1,sig1) = wav.read("/home/pi/OpenCalculator.wav")
(rate2,sig2) = wav.read("/home/pi/voiceCommand.wav")
mfcc1 = mfcc(sig1,rate1)
mfcc2 = mfcc(sig2,rate2)

dist, path = fastdtw(mfcc1, mfcc2)

elapsed = time.time()-start
```

And this is error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/test.py", line 23, in <module>
    dist, path = fastdtw(mfcc1, mfcc2)
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/fastdtw.py", line 20, in fastdtw
    distance, path = fastdtw(x_shrinked, y_shrinked, radius=radius, dist=dist)
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/fastdtw.py", line 20, in fastdtw
    distance, path = fastdtw(x_shrinked, y_shrinked, radius=radius, dist=dist)
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/fastdtw.py", line 20, in fastdtw
    distance, path = fastdtw(x_shrinked, y_shrinked, radius=radius, dist=dist)
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/fastdtw.py", line 20, in fastdtw
    distance, path = fastdtw(x_shrinked, y_shrinked, radius=radius, dist=dist)
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/fastdtw.py", line 20, in fastdtw
    distance, path = fastdtw(x_shrinked, y_shrinked, radius=radius, dist=dist)
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/fastdtw.py", line 20, in fastdtw
    distance, path = fastdtw(x_shrinked, y_shrinked, radius=radius, dist=dist)
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/fastdtw.py", line 20, in fastdtw
    distance, path = fastdtw(x_shrinked, y_shrinked, radius=radius, dist=dist)
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/fastdtw.py", line 20, in fastdtw
    distance, path = fastdtw(x_shrinked, y_shrinked, radius=radius, dist=dist)
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/fastdtw.py", line 20, in fastdtw
    distance, path = fastdtw(x_shrinked, y_shrinked, radius=radius, dist=dist)
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/fastdtw.py", line 16, in fastdtw
    return dtw(x, y, window = None, dist=dist)
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/fastdtw.py", line 34, in dtw
    D[i, j][0] += dist(x[i-1], y[j-1])
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

*** output of mccc is in numpy array form.
Please help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redefine distance to work with feature vectors instead of numbers (default distance works with numbers, not with vectors):

```
def mfcc_dist(a,b):
      dist = 0
      for x, y in zip(a,b):
          dist = dist + (x - y) * (x - y)
      return sqrt(dist)

dist, path = fastdtw(mfcc1, mfcc2, dist=mfcc_dist)
```

You can also use `numpy.linalg.norm(a-b)`.

Comment: No, a and b are not wave1 and wave2, they are local variables in dist function. Default dist function is `lambda a, b: abs(a - b)`, you need to redefine it.

Comment: Oh ok I got it but why in run file I can't print out the dist that is output from fastdtw. It said syntax error. I'm so confusing

Comment: I can print it out sorry for asking stupid question. I just remove unused import "from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals"

Comment: Thank you so much I finally can run it without error. I stuck with it for 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

`mfcc1` and `mfcc2` should be list or numpy array. Do they have correct type?

Comment: output of mccc is in numpy array form.